# Jibri for Jitsi on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, jitsi, jitsi-meet, video-conferencing

I have set up a working jitsi (web/jicofo/prosody/jvb) configuration in a single pod on a custom kubernetes cluster and I'm trying to bring in the Jibri to enable recording features. But it fails cause there is an error log on the jibri container as follows.

> Jibri 2022-06-01 08:32:05.409 WARNING: [29] [hostname=localhost id=localhost] MucClient.lambda$getConnectAndLoginCallable$7#661: Failed to join the MUCs.
> org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException$XMPPErrorException: XMPP error reply received from jibribrewery@internal-muc.meet.jitsi/jibri-653057866: XMPPError: not-allowed - cancel [Room creation is restricted]

Most of the articles and forums suggests to add the ENABLE_RECORDING in the jicofo container, but it was not successful for me.

[jitsi community answer](https://community.jitsi.org/t/jibri-xmpperror-not-allowed-cancel/104282)

[github answer](https://github.com/jitsi/docker-jitsi-meet/issues/1174)

As I understand the XMPP_INTERNAL_MUC_DOMAIN is important and I have used the value: "internal-muc.meet.jits"

Anybody got any idea on how to fix it?

PS im using stable-7001 version across all containers

Thanks in advance